# How can I change for loop while in it?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
for x in file.readlines():
    something()
```

I think this code caching all the lines when loop is started. I deleting some of the lines from the file but it still repeating deleted lines. How can I change loop while in it?

```
def wanted(s,d):
    print("deneme = " + str(s))
    count = 0
    total = 0
    TG_count = TC_count = TA_count = GC_count = CC_count = CG_count = GG_count = AA_count = AT_count = TT_count = CT_count = AG_count = AC_count = GT_count = 0
    for x in range(d,fileCount):
        print(str(x+1) + 'st file processing...')
        searchFile = open(str(x) + '.txt',encoding = 'utf-8',mode = "r+")
        l = searchFile.readlines()
        searchFile.seek(0)
        for line in l:
            if s in line[:12]:
                blabla()
            else:
                searchFile.write(line)
        searchFile.truncate()
        searchFile.close()

for p in range(fileCount):
  searchFile = open(str(p) + '.txt',encoding = 'utf-8',mode = "r+")
  for z in searchFile.readlines():
      wanted(z[:12],p)
  print("Progressing file " + str(p) + " complete")
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Python.........

Comment: Then put that as a tag for your question.

Comment: Either you will get errors when you run this code, in this case post the error messages, too, or you didn't paste the code correctly, in this case please post the code that you actually use.

Comment: I pasted all the required parts and I think my question is not that hard. I hope I can get help instead of negative feedback.

Comment: are the last 5 lines actually part of the ''wanted'' function?

Comment: it seems that these variables that are initialized by 0 are useless becaue they aren't used after initialization. The variable fileCount seems to be a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's Python. Yes, `readlines()` reads the whole file at once. In order to avoid this you can use:

```
for x in file:
    something()
```

Comment: @Tuğberk - You need to provide a [mcve] showing how the lines are deleted and what you expect to happen. Also include a source file.

Comment: I added........ As you see, I deleting lines from the file. My loop contains lines and I want to change them lines while running loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find the appropriate information in the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects). It says

> If you want to read all the lines of a file in a list you can also use list(f) or f.readlines().
>   So yes, all lines are read and stored in memory.

Also the manual says:

> f.readline() reads a single line from the file; 
>   More details can be found in the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=truncate#module-io).